# Hector quadcopter not responding to cmd_vel messages

Tags: control, ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been following this tutorial to get the hector quadcopter to work: http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo

I'm using Kinetic and I can see that the tutorial is a bit outdated so I have used

```
wstool init src https://raw.github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/kinetic-devel/tutorials.rosinstall
```

instead of the URL specified in the tutorial. catkin_make completes with no errors.

I do not have access to a controller at hand so I intend to use my keyboard for the time being. I could not find the pr2_teleop package mentioned for Kinetic but I found somewhere that teleop_twist_keyboard ( http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard ) should work just fine. I start the controller using

```
rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
```

I have monitored the cmd_vel topic that, according to the tutorial, is being used and the telop_twist_keyboard node does publish messages just fine.

Here is a graph of my nodes that verifies the connection between the gazebo node and teleop_twist_keyboard using the cmd_vel:

[image: image description]

However the drone does not move whatsoever and I can't find any error messages (besides one that says no joystick was found at /dev/input/js0) but I would not expect that to be the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256590/hector-quadcopter-not-responding-to-cmd_vel-messages/) by [mathiasi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28445/mathiasi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I stumbled upon this issue: https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/issues/66
Turns out that you have to an enable_motors action to "turn on" the quadcopter.
Calling

```
rosservice call /enable_motors true
```

worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [mathiasi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28445/mathiasi/) with karma: 31 on 2017-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0